# Date concatenating in new column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe with column `date` with type `datetime64[ns]`.

When I try to create new column day with format `MM-DD` based on date column only first method works from below. Why second method doesn't work in pandas?

```
df['day'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%m-%d')
df['day2'] = str(df['date'].dt.month) + '-' + str(df['date'].dt.day)
```

Result for one row:

```
day                                                  01-04
day2     0       1\n1       1\n2       1\n3       1\n4 ...
```

Types of columns

```
day              object
day2             object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem of solution is if use `str` with `df['date'].dt.month` it return `Series`, correct way is use [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df['day2'] = df['date'].dt.month.astype(str) + '-' + df['date'].dt.day.astype(str)
```